# ngRepeat $index is not displaying properly in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The [Angular JS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat) say the ngRepeat directive is supposed to set the $index variable to the item index in the array. This works fine in Chrome and IE 10, but IE 9 shows "{{$index}}" instead of the number. Here is a small example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Host Parameters</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
    <style>
        .host-param-table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .host-param-table td, .host-param-table th {
            border: 1px solid gray;
            text-align:center;
            padding: 2px;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-family: Arial;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="ng-app" data-ng-app>
<div data-ng-controller="HostParametersCtrl">
    <table class="host-param-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>On</th>
            <th>Value (Hex)</th>
            <th>Value (Output)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="p in params">
            <td>{{p.name}}</td>
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td><input data-ng-model="p.isEnabled" type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input data-ng-model="p.value" data-ng-disabled="!p.isEnabled" type="text" /></td>
            <td>0x{{p.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function HostParametersCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.params = [
            { 'isEnabled': false, 'name': 'First', 'value': '' },
            { 'isEnabled': false, 'name': 'Second', 'value': '' },
            { 'isEnabled': false, 'name': 'Third', 'value': '' },
            { 'isEnabled': false, 'name': 'Fourth', 'value': '' },
            { 'isEnabled': false, 'name': 'Fifth', 'value': '' },
            { 'isEnabled': false, 'name': 'Sixth', 'value': '' },
            { 'isEnabled': false, 'name': 'Seventh', 'value': '' }
        ];

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Viewed in Chrome 29:

[image: Chrome]

Viewed in IE 9:

[image: Internet Exploiter 9]

Note that the checkboxes disable the inputs as expected. It's just the index that's broken. Today is my first day using Angular JS so I'm hoping that there is something simple I forgot and this is an easy fix. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is Angular working at all in IE? Are you seeing p.name populated?

Comment: @BoxerBucks The binding appears to be working but the $index variable is not. That is why I think I did something wrong. At first nothing was working, but adding `id="ng-app"` fixed most of it. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: It's probably a bootstrapping issue... i used $index and it was working  on IE7... Can you provide us a plunker or a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a plunkr with your code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ajHZ04yqnBmKHUicWmgb?p=preview - I modified it a bit.

When I view that same codebase on my local PC using IE, it runs the same in IE8, 9 and 10. It does not run at all in IE7.

Unfortunately, I don't think plunkr supports IE8, or 9, so just paste the code into your file and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Well this is odd. IE 8 on a different computer displays properly (both my original code and your code). Is it possible that an outdated version of IE 8 or 9 could be missing some crucial update?

Comment: idk.. maybe. Use the developer tools and make sure its not getting put into a different mode due to a security setting or something.